# How would you describe thinking in the dark?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idiom-request

[image]

It happens usually in the bed, when all the light is out. This would reduce all stimuli significantly, so you can analyze/use your imagination best. I take a look a some synonyms for "think" but don't know what to choose:

> ponder, reflect, deliberate, meditate, contemplate, muse, cogitate, ruminate, be lost in thought, be in a brown study, brood, concentrate, rack one's brains, cudgel one's brains, put on one's thinking cap, sleep on it, cerebrate

My objective is to find an illustration that can describe that state of thinking.

Comment: *wonder* and *lose myself in thoughts* would be my choice, purely out of intuition.

Comment: Sounds a bit like [sensory deprivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensory_deprivation)

Comment: `x-request` questions should give a sample sentence with a blank where the `x` should go.

Answer (score 1):

Your paragraph is awkwardly phrased.  I might say something like this:
I do some of my best thinking in bed at night, when the lights are out and all is quiet.

Reflecting on the events of the day, I concluded that my boss and I have different priorities.  Since I couldn't sleep, I contemplated my options for tomorrow.